# How can I create a reusable envelope in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to integrate DocuSign into my System for embedded signing. I understand that I can do this by calling an endpoint `/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient`.

But, in this I have to provide a document on every single request for each user(email address). Is there any way that I can create an envelope once and then reuse it for every single user (email) of my system by just passing an envelopeId and different signer name and signer email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your scenario correctly, using a DocuSign **Template** would enable you to achieve your goal.

Simply use the DocuSign web UI to create a **Template** and as part of creating that Template, you can specify things like the document(s) it includes, a *recipient role* for each recipient, etc.

Then, to create/send an Envelope using the API, you can use the [Create Envelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) operation and as part of the API request specify the `templateId` and specify recipient information (name, email, clientUserId, etc.) using `templateRoles`. For example:

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

{
    "emailSubject": "Please sign",
    "templateId": TEMPLATE_ID,
    "templateRoles": [{
        "email": EMAIL,
        "name": RECIPIENT_NAME,
        "roleName": TEMPLATE_ROLE_NAME
    }],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Note: This is a simplified example that doesn't account for things like pre-populating tabs with values as part of the Create/Send Envelope API request. If you want to pre-populate tabs as part of the API request, you'll need to use a `compositeTemplates` structure within the API request. There's lots of info here on Stack Overflow about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to provide a document of every single `/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient request`. You will create an envelope once with all the required recipients, and everytime you want to host an embedded signing ceremony then you will call `/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient` for each recipient. It is important to note that you need to put unique clientUserId for each recipient in an envelope, so that you when you calling "createRecipient" call for a recipient then you can pass same clientUserId which you have used while creating an envelope.

You can see example for embedded signing at https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/embedded_signing.html

Comment: What if I don't have all the recipients(signer information) when I create envelop?

Comment: Or should I be using template to create an envelop?

Comment: You don't have signer information means? If you don't have signer information then how you will do the signing ceremony, you need to have email and name of the signer before starting signing ceremony for that signer. You can create an envelope with dummy recipients by adding clientUserId for each recipient, once you get actual recipient email/name then you can update the recipient details using `PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients` call, then you can call "createRecipient" API to start the signing ceremony

Comment: For example, I have one recipient information and in future I will have, for say, 1000(this number is variable and I don't have information, how many it can be) recipients who will sign same document, then how can I create envelop with dummy data?

Comment: So will there be a scenario that 1000 (n number) of recipients will sign the envelope, if you don't know how many recipients are planning to sign then how would you place their signing tabs on the document, because each signer tab has to be associated with a signer only. Its better if you share your usecase in detail so that we can get good understanding of the workflow.